# Salesforce, select from database and add to the list of Contacts

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I would like select query from SOQL, and add to the list of Contacts and return it.

```
public class ContactSearch {
    public static List<Contact> searchForContacts(String sLastName, String sMailingPostalCode) {
        List<Contact> listFromDatabase = new List<Contact>();
        listFromDatabase = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE (LastName=:sLastName AND MailingPostalCode=:sMailingPostalCode)];
        
        return listFromDatabase;
    }
}
```

But there is an error: "Illegal assignment from List to List" at line 4. Why please? I use API version 51.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and it works like a charm? What editor you're using, maybe needs updating?

[image]

You could simplify it to just

```
return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE LastName=:sLastName AND MailingPostalCode=:sMailingPostalCode];
```

No point initialising a list if you're going to overwrite it in next line.

Comment: I compiled it in Developer Console in "My Trailhead Playground 1".
It's challenge in modul [link]https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql

I tried also
`
return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE LastName=:sLastName AND MailingPostalCode=:sMailingPostalCode];
`
but there is an error too.

[link]https://pasteboard.co/JRvVl3o.png

Comment: Sorry mate, worked like a charm for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg6vT.png You sure you're picking right trailhead org/developer edition to check the challenge in? Maybe you have 2 orgs and one of them has class with same name but no such function? What error it gives if body of your function is just that 1-liner `return [SELECT Id...]`? Want to jump on a Zoom call, Google Hangouts or something?

Comment: I have open 'My Trailhead Playground 1'.
And I try other tool, not Developer Console, but Apex Classes.
And there is the same bug.
[https://pasteboard.co/JRMULmM.png](https://pasteboard.co/JRMULmM.png)

Comment: Crazy. Maybe you have some weird Unicode characters in there. Can you copy paste this: `public static List<Contact>`?v What happens when you do `List<Contact> x = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 10];` in developer console's "execute anonymous? And 1 more thing - what are the chances you created a Class (or Visualforce page) named "Contact"? that name would "shadow" the name of the standard object...

Comment: 1.) Code with `public static List<Contact>` is an error: "public is not allowed on locals at line 3 collumn 37"
[https://pasteboard.co/JROr4ic.png](https://pasteboard.co/JROr4ic.png)
2.) In Developer Console: `List<Contact> x = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 10];` is an error: "Illegal assignment from List to List"
[https://pasteboard.co/JROrAWv.png](https://pasteboard.co/JROrAWv.png)
But, in Query Editor is 'SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 10' ok and return result.
[https://pasteboard.co/JROrYvw.png](https://pasteboard.co/JROrYvw.png)

Comment: 3.) Name of Class is 'ContactSearch'. I don't know to use VisualForce. I haven't learned it yet.

Comment: Can you create a new "hands on org" or developer edition or however it's described in that Launch menu in trailhead and try there. Is that the only class in the org? (Setup -> Apex classes). I really suspect there's some name clash.

Comment: You are genius. It's done. I created new Playground and there in Apex classes I created this method and it's without mistakes.
[Challenge is completed](https://pasteboard.co/JRW7oeK.png)
Thank you.